# PrimeFaces: ChartJs stacked bar chart label removal

Tags: javascript, java, primefaces, chart.js

I am developing a dashboard, and in it I have a chart with some sales rep data. Here's my code and an image.

```
//xhtml element:
<p:panel  header="Oportunidades">
    <p:barChart id="graficoOportunidadesRepresentante" model="#{dashboardBean.barModel}" style="width:100%; height:420px"/>         
</p:panel>  

//Bean generation method:
public void criaGraficoOportunidadesPorRepresentante() {
    barModel = new BarChartModel();
    ChartData data = new ChartData();
    [...]
    data.setLabels(labels); //comes from the related sales rep's name
    barModel.setData(data); //backend fetches amounts from database

    // Options
    BarChartOptions options = new BarChartOptions();
    CartesianScales cScales = new CartesianScales();
    CartesianLinearAxes linearAxes = new CartesianLinearAxes();
    linearAxes.setStacked(true);
    cScales.addXAxesData(linearAxes);
    cScales.addYAxesData(linearAxes);
    options.setScales(cScales);

    Title title = new Title();
    title.setDisplay(true);
    title.setText(labelGraficoOportunidadesAtivas);
    options.setTitle(title);

    Tooltip tooltip = new Tooltip();
    tooltip.setMode("index");
    tooltip.setIntersect(false);
    options.setTooltip(tooltip);
    
    barModel.setExtender("chartOportunidadePorRepresentanteExtender");
    barModel.setOptions(options);
}
    
//Javascript extender: 
    function chartOportunidadePorRepresentanteExtender() {                             
               var options = $.extend(true, {}, this.cfg.config);
                options = {
                 options: {             
                    plugins: {
                      labels: {
                        render: 'value',
                        position: 'inside'
                      }
                    },
                    title: {
                        fontSize: 16
                    }
                  }
                  };           
               $.extend(true, this.cfg.config, options);
            };
```

I want the numbers on the bars to not render, because they are better legible on the element's tooltip, and are stacking on top of one another
[as per this screenshot.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P77Vo.png) AFAIK, *label* refers to the name of the rep, and each dataset also has a ".setLabel(String)" method that's rendering between the chart title and content. I've found some solutions refering to a *"legend"* property, but it de-rendered the so far called *label* property.

Comment: Maybe I don't understand but no numbers are on the bars in this example? https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/chartjs/bar/bar.xhtml they are only on the tooltips.

Comment: Exactly, and my code is pretty much the same as the example (except for the extender, whose removal just changed from round numbers to percentile)

Comment: have you tried removing the Extender to see what it looks like?  Your extender might be wiping out other settings because i see you are setting `labels`.

Comment: Yes, and by doing so instead of numbers I got percentile values on top of the bars

Comment: Weird that the PF Showcase would not have the same behavior but it does not?  Something about yours must be different.

Answer (score 0):

I've managed it. In the js extender:

```
labels: {
         render: 'value',
         fontSize: 0
         }
```

I don't even know why I removed the "position: inside" value, I just did. fontSize = 0 hid the numbers.